# My monitor has suddenly started showing shadows at the TOP and BOTTOM of the screen. Is it broken?

Tags: display, external-display

Here's a screen shot of my monitor. Some time today (and since then) it's been like this.

[image]

I've tried connecting my computer + the same HDMI cable to another monitor and it seemed to work 100% ok there.

So is this means my monitor is now dead? Or can it be fixed with some smart software command, etc?

Thanks in advance to any help!

Comment: Definitely a hardware issue.

Comment: Looks like backlight diffuser has shifted or the lights are dying around the edges.

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like a software problem but like a plain hardware issue.
Best you can do is check for the screens warranty and get it replaced by the vendor if its still in warranty scope.

Comment: Nope - probably out of warranty :( It's a few years old now.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a hardware issue.
I actually experienced a similar issue with my monitor that turned out to be a bad power supply brick.

I replaced the lead and brick and it fixed the issue.
Mine was not quite as extreme dimming as yours appears to be but it might be worth a go.

Comment: Wow. interesting, I'll give that a go later on when I get back home!